# Simple script generating captcha usable in local GUI

Tags: php, python, captcha

I have developed a GUI in python. At boot, my program asks the users some info: just a simple email. The program sends the email to my server, the server records the user (in a database), and responds a user_id. For now, anyone with the URL of the signing page could spam my database.

The user_id is then stored locally, and the user needs it to run the program.

I would like to use a captcha. The program should get a captcha from the server at boot. If the user enters and sends the correct captcha, the server records the user and responds.

Do you have an idea about how to do that ?

I can only use the modules listed here, because I have a shared hosting:

http://perso.ovh.net/infos/

I can use both python and PHP, that's not a problem for me (I have a small preference for python, however). I would like to not rely on an external service, like reCaptcha.

Comment: Are you looking for captcha libraries, like https://github.com/Gregwar/Captcha ?

Comment: If I can use it on my server simply by drag-n-droping it, yes. Also, avoiding the use of sessions would be a plus. Using also python would be perfect.

Comment: Using a session for the captcha phrase to be compared to the user input in your backend logic would be the way to go.